# how to render parsed XML image source as an image (instead of string)

Tags: android, gridview, xml-parsing

I'm trying to extract xml data from a web page and use the information to fill in a GridView layout with Images. I've successfully collected title, description(which includes the image link), and web  address of each article on this particular web page (theoatmeal.com). The problem now is that I've only collected strings...so far this is okay for the link/address and title...but for displaying the images, I need an image array, the string that points to the address of the image isn't enough.

You can see my Main runnable class SelectionGrid has most of the program, I've also made a separate class called OatmealItems.Java that defines the elements I will be collecting from theoameal.com XML feed, and then I store the OatmealItems objects in a list of type OatmealItems.

For now I just have the titles of each article occupying the grid, but I need to get images in there, can anyone help me out?

here is the link to the XML feed :  http://feeds.feedburner.com/oatmealfeed

### SelectionGrid.Java

```
public class SelectionGrid extends Activity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener 
{

    TextView selection; 
    private List<OatmealItems> oatmealItems = new ArrayList<OatmealItems>();
    private List<String> Titles = new ArrayList<String>();
    private List<String> IMAGES = new ArrayList<String>();

    static String Address = "http://feeds.feedburner.com/oatmealfeed?format=xml";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.main);

         selection=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.selection);
         GridView myGridView=(GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid);

         HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
         HttpGet getMethod = new HttpGet(Address);

         try {
            ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler=new BasicResponseHandler();
            String responseBody=client.execute(getMethod, responseHandler); 
            buildOatmealItem(responseBody);
            LoadTitleArray();
            ArrayAdapter<String> myArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, Titles);
            myGridView.setAdapter(myArrayAdapter);
            myGridView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
          }
        catch (Throwable t)
            {

            t.getMessage();
            Toast.makeText(this, "Crap.... "+t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();            
        }//catch

    }


void buildOatmealItem(String raw) throws Exception 
{
            DocumentBuilder builder=DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();

            Document doc=builder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(raw)));

            NodeList titles=doc.getElementsByTagName("title");
            NodeList link=doc.getElementsByTagName("link");
            NodeList description=doc.getElementsByTagName("description");

            for (int i=0;i<titles.getLength();i++) 
            {
                Element Atitle=(Element)titles.item(i);
                Element Alink=(Element)link.item(i);
                Element Adescription=(Element)description.item(i);
                OatmealItems oatmealitem=new OatmealItems(Atitle.getTextContent(), Alink.getTextContent(), Adescription.getTextContent());

                oatmealItems.add(oatmealitem);
            }
        }


    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) 
    {
        selection.setText(oatmealItems.get(position).getImageURL());
    }


    public void LoadTitleArray()
    {
        for (int i=0; i<oatmealItems.size(); i++)
        {
            String  title = oatmealItems.get(i).getTitle();
            Titles.add(title);
        }

        }

    }

}
```

### OatmealItems.Java

```
    public class OatmealItems 
    {

              private String title;
              private String link;
              private String imageURL;

              public String getTitle()      { return title; }
              public String getLink()       { return link; }
              public String getDescription(){ return imageURL; }

              public OatmealItems(String _title,  String _link, String _description) 
              {

                title = _title;
                link = _link;
                imageURL =  _description;
              }

////// this method was supposed to parse the description tag and extract the image src that's embedded
              //public String ExtractImageFromDescriptionTag(String description)
              //{
                  //String y=description.replace("&lt;","<");
                  //String x;
                  //x=y.replace("&gt;",">");
                  //String[] items = x.split("><"); 
                  //String[] theLink = items[1].split("\"");; 
                  //return theLink[1];

              //}


              @Override
              public String toString() 
              {   

                return "title: " + title +"----------\n\n" + "link: "+ link+ "----------\n\n" +"imageURL: " +imageURL ;  
              }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to find a pattern which is **src="image url"** in your **description** string.
To understand, how it works: http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html